# target and rel attributes not working on style.css

Tags: css, attributes

I want to have these 2 attributes in a class on my stylesheet: `target="_blank"` and `rel="noopener noreferrer"`

The attributes work perfectly fine when I include them directly in a tag (`<a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">example</a>`).

But when I try to put the 2 into a class (below), I get an error where `target` and `rel` are not recognized as attributes.

```
.link {
  target: _blank
  rel: noopener noreferrer
}
```

Comment: You can't set attributes using CSS. You need to use JavaScript to do what you're attempting.

Comment: Read me: https://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-rel-attribute.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this using JavaScript, not CSS

Add an event listener to the document that waits for the document to be loaded, then get all of the elements with the `.link` class and set the relevant attributes.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll(".link");
  var numLinks = links.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < numLinks; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    link.setAttribute("rel", "noopener noreferrer");
  }
});
```